# how to integrate facebook visitors posts and watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

We'd like to answer facebook visitors'posts through watson conversation(not facebook messenger), is there any node js sample(or others...) for it ?

Thanks

Comment: our requirement: if someone posts anything on my fan page(not messenger), watson conversation will take over and answer it automatically

Answer (score 0):

In Watson Conversation, click on the "Deploy" button on the left. There will be an option there pointing you to how to deploy to BotKit.

[image]

Here is the direct link to the project.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware